# Loss click scrolling in a CScrollView containing several CWnd

Tags: c++, mfc, vertical-scrolling

I have an architecture based on a `CScrollView` containing several `CWnd` (here just one for test)
[image]

All display aspects work fine including scrolling with the mouse wheel but there is one problem:

- I lose scroll by click (with the mouse or with the [Stylus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_(computing))) if I click on the area of ​​a `CWnd` window and I try to scroll. On the other hand, if I click on an area which not containing a `CWnd` everything works fine.

I already tried to forward the `WM_VSCROLL` messages from the `CWnd` to the `CScrollView` but it doesn't work

What did I forget in my architecture to make it work?

**Environment:**

- Visual studio 2010
- C++11

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information for anyone to try and assist you. They would need just kind of test project that replicates your problem.

Comment: The scroll from CScrollView is handled automatically by call SetSize() method. For those mini CWnd you have to handle yourself.

Comment: Couldn't you just catch the `WM_SETFOCUS` and move the focus back to the parent? So in the `CWnd::OnSetFocus` method, do not call base implementation, then call `GetParent()->SetFocus();`

Comment: @Andry thanks. i resolved my broblem by doing something similar, i catch the onclick coordinates in child window, after i calculate delta (y1-y2). Y1 is vertical coordinate when i click, y2 is vertical cordinate when i release mouse button. After, i forward delta to the parent window :)